# Download Manager Downloads .bin File Only

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I have a problem with the download manager in android. I am trying to download a .mp4 video file from a webview but no matter what I did, it always download the file with .bin extenstion. it is not related to the filename, I know because I tried both `guessFileName()` function and manually entering a name but the result is same. In other browsers, there is no problem downloading the content(.mp4). One issue may be about mimetype, it returns `"application/octet-stream"` therefore I tried `request.setMimeType("video/mp4");` but still I get the mimetype unchanged.

onCreate:

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
            request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
            request.setMimeType(mimetype);
            request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
            request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype));
            request.setDescription("Downloading File...");
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype));
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            Log.i("TAG1", url);
            Log.i("TAG1", contentDisposition);
            Log.i("TAG1", mimetype);

            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

            dm.enqueue(request);
```

MyWebViewClient class:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}
```

Logs:

```
I/TAG1: http://someurl.com/someurl
I/TAG1: attachment; filename="filename.mp4"
I/TAG1: application/octet-stream
```

One additional note: Downloading happens after redirecting the URL to other URL. But I have tried downloading without redirecting the URL, and still got the .bin file.

Comment: Why do you `enqueue` on a seperate thread? `DownloadManager` is main thread safe by default

Comment: I don't know, I have been experimenting with what I have seen online. I removed the separate thread now.

Comment: Share your Url in both cases i.e before redirect and after

Comment: Android version of used device?

Comment: @blackapps I am using Android version 11 to test, but the app supports back until the 4.4

Comment: @zarez. me  too have same uses case kindly help me resolve this

Answer (score 0):

Removing

```
ForceType application/octet-stream
```

from .htaccess solves the issue

Comment: me too have same uses case kindly help me resolve this

Answer (score 0):

I think it happening because mimetype is empty.

Please try this `webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                    long contentLength) {
            String fileExtension = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getExtensionFromMimeType(mimetype);

            if(fileExtension == null || fileExtension.isEmpty()){
                fileExtension = "mp4";
            }

            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                    Uri.parse(url));
            String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
            request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
            request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
            request.setMimeType(mimetype);

            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED); //Notify client once download is completed!
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, fileExtension));
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", //To notify the Client that the file is being downloaded
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });`
```